# Flutter Firebase access data from main collection

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am having an issue accessing the main collection list of my Firebase. So I have 4 main collections, and some sub-collections. However I am looking to achieve the following in my code:

If Catering (from the application) = catering (the main collection from the Firestore database) => Display the items of the catering collection. Please refer to the image. Does anyone know how I can access the main collections?

Thank you

[image: My Screen]

I don't really see an alternative solution, as it is a event planning app, and if I just have one long supplier database with a `.where()` to find each one of my supplier types, It's just going to be confusing, so the easiest way is to have collection of each supplier type and add the supplier to that.

Comment: please add your code so that we can able to see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store your supplier types in a separate document.

For example,

`Suppliers (Collection)` -> `AllSuppliers (Document)`.

Then create a list inside that document that stores the list of suppliers.

You can update the AllSuppliers Document whenever you want to add a new supplier type.

Inside your app you fetch the single document containing the list of supplier types and show a list view accordingly.

And then whenever a user clicks on a list item you load the suppliers for the supplier type.

Comment: The issue is if I use : Suppliers (Collection) -> Catering (Document) , I then get : Suppliers (1st Collection) -> Catering (1st Document) -> Catering Supplier (2nd Collection) -> Caterer A(2nd Documents) So in my app once I create a listTile with all the 1st documents (Catering, Flower ..), when clicking on that I am not able to reach the 2nd documents(Caterer A, Caterer B ...)